# why mongoose does not make query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have very simular rout for `GET` and `findOne()` query that work with mongosee, but PUT and updateOne() is not. Why?

**routes**

```
router.put("/user/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  userService.updateOne(String(req.params.id), {$set: req.body[0]}, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
       console.log(req.params.id);
       console.log(req.body[0]);
       console.log("we must be in mongoose!")
      res.json(res.data);
    } else {
      console.log(Number(req.params.id));
      res.status(400);
      res.end();
    }
  });
});
```

**reopository**

```
function updateById(id, body, callback) {
  var model = this.model;
  var query = model.updateOne(
    {
    _id: id 
    },
    {
      body
    });
  query.exec(callback);
}
```

**services**

```
updateOne: (id, body, callback) => {
    UserRepository.updateById(id, body, (err, data) => {

      callback(err, data);
    })
  }
```

thats all!
[image]

Comment: Maybe callback in updateOne function: model.updateOne({ _id: id }, { body }}, callback);

Comment: @Nico u mean model.updateOne({{ _id: id }, { body }}, callback)? it's called exceptions